# Simple past or present perfect?

Tags: tense, idiomatic-language

Simple past or present perfect? Would one of them be more natural to use here or are they practically interchangeable?

Example: A young man has hit a woman with his car. He immediately calls his mom.

Son: Mom, I/I've just hit a woman with my car. I think she's dead.

Dad: What's wrong?

Mom: It's Ben. He/He's just killed a woman.

Dad: He did what?/He has done what?

Comment: The **present perfect** lends greater immediacy to a situation although English speakers  may well use either or both in situations like these.

Comment: Could the dad respond "He did what?" to "He's just killed a woman" or would that not be natural?

Answer (score 1):

Both make sense, but it is probably more natural to say,

> Mom: He's just killed a woman.
>
> Dad: He did what?!

i.e. the present perfect.

Comment: Do you mean: He's done what?! Or is it okay to mix the tenses?

Comment: Native English speakers mix them all the time. The question is: What is the context? Are you preparing for an examination or are you writing a novel? In conversation, English speakers don't reflect on which tense they are using. They certainly don't aim to be consistent or correct.